# Unable to set shellhook using SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: c++, windows

I'm not sure what the problem is, I am registering a hook and following the documentation.  I've read it all, but for some reason it's not working.  It will tell me the hook was installed, but then it will never be called.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>

HHOOK hHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK ShellProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   
    wprintf( TEXT("ShellProc called with iCode: %d\r\n"), nCode );

    if( nCode == HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED )
    {
        HWND hWnd = (HWND)wParam;

        wprintf( TEXT("New window created: %d\r\n"), hWnd );
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, (HOOKPROC)ShellProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());

    if( hHook == NULL )
    {
        wprintf( TEXT("Failed to set windows hook\r\n") );      
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf( TEXT("Windows hook set.\r\n") );
        MINIMIZEDMETRICS st;
        st.cbSize = sizeof(MINIMIZEDMETRICS);
        st.iArrange = ARW_HIDE;
        BOOL ret;
        ret = SystemParametersInfo(
            SPI_SETMINIMIZEDMETRICS,
            sizeof(MINIMIZEDMETRICS),
            &st,
            0);

    }

    do
    {
        Sleep(100);
    } while( !GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F5) );

    if( hHook != NULL )
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are installing the hook into the calling thread only, and then that thread is not doing anything that would cause the hook to be invoked.  [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx#wh_shellhook):

> The system calls a WH_SHELL hook procedure when the shell application is about to be activated and when a top-level window is created or destroyed

You are not doing any of that.

On a side note, you should not be calling `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMINIMIZEDMETRICS)` at all unless your app is intended to replace Explorer.exe as the registered Shell app for managing the Windows desktop.